# Dependent Insert with Multi Row Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, bulkinsert

We have a CRM system using SQL Server and are looking to populate all customers with an email address, even if that email address is NULL.

There is a Customer table, a table for Email addresses and a Linker table.

I can perform a `SELECT` query for all customers who need a new Email row:

```
SELECT @CompanyId = Comp_CompanyId
FROM Company
WHERE Company.Comp_CompanyId NOT IN (
  SELECT ELink_RecordID
  FROM EmailLink
)
```

and I can perform the `INSERT` statements to add an Email address to a customer:

```
DECLARE @EmailId int
DECLARE @ELinkId int

EXEC @ELinkId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'
EXEC @EmailId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'

INSERT INTO Email (
  Emai_EmailId,
  Emai_CreatedBy,
  Emai_CreatedDate,
  Emai_UpdatedBy,
  Emai_UpdatedDate,
  Emai_TimeStamp,
  Emai_EmailAddress
)
VALUES (
  @EmailId,
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  NULL
)
INSERT INTO EmailLink(
  ELink_LinkID,
  ELink_CreatedBy,
  ELink_CreatedDate,
  ELink_UpdatedBy,
  ELink_UpdatedDate,
  ELink_TimeStamp,
  ELink_EntityID,
  ELink_RecordID,
  ELink_Type,
  ELink_EmailId
)
VALUES(
  @ELinkId,
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  5,          -- Person is 13, Company is 5
  COMPANY_ID_GOES_HERE,
  'Business',
  @EmailId
)
```

Is there a way I can combine these into one big SQL statement without having to use an external tool? I can write a quick Python program to do this, but the people maintaining this longterm are SQL focused.

The furthest I've got is combining the `SELECT` with the `INSERT` for the email, but couldn't figure out how to then `INSERT` the linker row:

```
DECLARE @CompanyId int
DECLARE @EmailId int
DECLARE @ELinkId int

EXEC @ELinkId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'
EXEC @EmailId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'

INSERT INTO Email (
  Emai_EmailId,
  Emai_CreatedBy,
  Emai_CreatedDate,
  Emai_UpdatedBy,
  Emai_UpdatedDate,
  Emai_TimeStamp,
  Emai_EmailAddress
)
VALUES (
  @EmailId,
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  NULL
)

SELECT @CompanyId = Comp_CompanyId
FROM Company
WHERE Company.Comp_CompanyId NOT IN (
  SELECT ELink_RecordID
  FROM EmailLink
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for the second part?

```
DECLARE @CompanyId int
DECLARE @EmailId int
DECLARE @ELinkId int

EXEC @ELinkId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'
EXEC @EmailId = eware_get_identity_id 'Email'

INSERT INTO Email (
  Emai_EmailId,
  Emai_CreatedBy,
  Emai_CreatedDate,
  Emai_UpdatedBy,
  Emai_UpdatedDate,
  Emai_TimeStamp,
  Emai_EmailAddress
)
VALUES (
  @EmailId,
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  1,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  NULL
)
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT CompanyId = Comp_CompanyId
    FROM Company
    WHERE Company.Comp_CompanyId 
    NOT IN (
            SELECT ELink_RecordID
            FROM EmailLink 
            )
)
INSERT INTO EmailLink(
  ELink_LinkID,
  ELink_CreatedBy,
  ELink_CreatedDate,
  ELink_UpdatedBy,
  ELink_UpdatedDate,
  ELink_TimeStamp,
  ELink_EntityID,
  ELink_RecordID,
  ELink_Type,
  ELink_EmailId
)
SELECT 
    @ELinkId,
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    5,          -- Person is 13, Company is 5
    X.CompanyId, --COMPANY_ID_GOES_HERE,
    'Business',
    @EmailId
FROM 
    cteX X
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get "Incorrect syntax near 'cteX'." returned. Also had to add the DECLARE and EXEC lines. That only has one INSERT out of the two and doesn't grab the IDs required from the EXEC stored procedures.

Comment: I've updated the answer, the incorrect syntax new cteX was due to missing semi colon

Comment: I still have some work to do to get this working, but that additional work was not covered by this question. Your solution works for what was asked. e.g. have to `EXEC` the stored procedure for each iteration.

Comment: @Metalshark I'm glad I could help